# program that sends an email to everyone registered in the database

Tags: java, sql, email

I'm 16 years old and no one to help me, no one to give any advice or constructive criticism, I'm aimless. I'll leave the link to my last code (github), a program that sends an email to everyone registered in the database. I would like some advice and project/content ideas for me to evolve. Evaluate my project sincerely.

Class that connects to the database and sends the email:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class JavaMailUtil {
    
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    String sender = "testemailforjava16@gmail.com";
    String senderPassword = "*******";
    
    private static Connection connectionToMySql() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emailproject?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
        return conn;
    }
    
    
    
    public void sendEmail(String title, String text) {
        conn = null;
        ps = null;
        rs = null;
        
        try {
            conn = connectionToMySql();
            ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("select * from users");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            while (rs.next() ) {
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
                prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
                
                Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(sender, senderPassword);
                    }       
                });
                
                Message message = prepareMessage(session, sender, rs.getString(2), text, title);
                
                Transport.send(message);
                
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
            
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
                
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email successfully sent!");
    }

    
    private static Message prepareMessage(Session session, String sender, String recepient, String text, String title) {
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recepient));
            message.setSubject(title);
            message.setText(text);
            return message;
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaMailUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return null;
        
    }
}
```

Swing Part:

```
package windows;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import project.JavaMailUtil;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class MainWindow {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField txtTitle;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Title:");
        lbl1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lbl1.setBounds(10, 81, 43, 26);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lbl1);
        
        JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Text:");
        lbl2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lbl2.setBounds(10, 133, 43, 26);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lbl2);
        
        txtTitle = new JTextField();
        txtTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtTitle.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        txtTitle.setBounds(54, 77, 342, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtTitle);
        txtTitle.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton buttonSend = new JButton("Send Email");
        buttonSend.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        buttonSend.setBounds(269, 227, 127, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonSend);
        
        JTextArea txtText = new JTextArea();
        txtText.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        txtText.setBounds(54, 136, 342, 80);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtText);
        txtText.setLineWrap(true);
        txtText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Automatic Sender");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 23));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(95, 22, 243, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JButton buttonUsers = new JButton("Users");
        buttonUsers.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        buttonUsers.setBounds(54, 227, 83, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonUsers);
        

        
        // TODO

        buttonSend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JavaMailUtil javaMailUtil = new JavaMailUtil();

                buttonSend.setText("Sending...");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sending... Wait the alert!");
                
                javaMailUtil.sendEmail(txtTitle.getText(), txtText.getText());
                buttonSend.setText("Send Email");
            }
        });
    
    }
}
```

Link: https://github.com/DaviRibeiro-prog/JAVA/tree/main/EmailSenderProject/src

Comment: Just be aware that we can only review/comment on the code that is actually in the question, not all the code in the repository.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome in the fantastic world of development.

There is this great acronym in software development: **S.O.L.I.D.**. You can refer to it at any time to evaluate the quality of your code.

However, in a two classes project, many of them are overkill. But there is one that you should try to use at all stages:

- ***"S"*** for "Single responsibility"

> Every class and method should have one responsibility

Your `JavaMailUtil` is responsible to connect to the database, retrieve the users and send emails. This is a bit too much.

You should better extract some functionalities to different classes. I see three main roles of your actual code:

1. Connect to the database
2. Retrieve the users
3. Send an email

The ***D**ata **A**ccess **O**bject* and the _**Factory** are two *design patterns* that you can use apply in you program.

The ***Factory*** will be used to get a connection to the database. While the _**DAO** can be used to get a list of users from that connection. Finally, your `JavaMailUtil` can use that ***DAO*** to retrieve the users.

- Another good principle is the **"D"** for "Dependency inversion".

The issue with the code above is that the `JavaMailUtil` has a strong dependency on your ***DAO*** to access the users. And, again, his role is to send emails, not retrieve users. A good solution is to pass the users as a parameter.

So you'll need a new class that will be responsible to retrieve the users and call the `sendEmail` method. It can be your `MainWindow` but ideally it is another class that should receive the command from the user facing interface and translate them to some actions on your program. Those classes are called *controllers* and are part of the ***M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller* pattern which is widely used in user facing applications.

I admit that I did not provide direct advice on your code. But with those few paragraphs you ave enough to learn and improve your program quite a bit.

Comment: I made a new post updating the code based on your comment, if you want check it out.